# php fatal error "Cannot access empty property" generated by foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I'm getting a "cannot access empty property error" on the line with the foreach in this code. `print_r($captions)` and `print_r($updates`) show the the expected values in each array.

`$updates` is an array of checked checkboxes where the user wants to update the captions for the photos. `$captions` is the array of all captions from the databases.

PHP processing shown here omits data sanitation for brevity. The codes gives the error with or without the sanitation routines.

```
if(isset($_POST['update']) && isset($_POST['caption'])){
    //check whether any photo captions are marked for update
    @$updates=$_POST['update'];
    @$captions=$_POST['caption'];           
    foreach($updates as $key->$photoid){
        $query="
        UPDATE photo 
        SET caption='".$captions[$key]."' 
        WHERE id='".$photoid."'
        LIMIT 1";
        $result=query($query);
        $message[]="Caption for photo # $photoid was successfully updated.";
    }
}
```

The form is generated by a loop that populates each row with a record (photoid, image, and caption) from the database and adds a checkbox to indicate whether user wants to update caption.

```
<tr>
    <td><? echo $thisphotoid; ?>.</td>
    <td><img src="<? echo '.SITE_URL.'images/banner/'.$thisfilename; ?>" /></td>
    <td><textarea name="caption[]" cols="40" rows="5"><? echo $thiscaption; ?></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="update[]" value="<? echo $thisphotoid; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `@$updates=$_POST['update'];` --- just curious, why do you need `@` there??

Comment: Don't use @ unless you absolutely know how it works and why you need it (which is never)

Comment: Someone recommended using @ whenever I use name[] for autogenerated rows in a form to indicate that it's an array. Not needed or  is there another way to do it?

Comment: @dac: that "someone" was wrong. Never follow his advices anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `$key->$photoid` to `$key => photoid`

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean:

```
foreach($updates as $key => $photoid) {
```